# Grids are displayed instead of maps when using mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I know there are a many questions on this topic. I have went to all of those questions and tried a lot of suggestions given in stack overflow and at other sites. But unfortunately, none has solved my problem.

When I am using MapView and MapsActivity, grid is displayed instead of maps. As suggested, I have regenerated API key and I have made sure that I have given the same package name as of my application, SHA1 key and I have enabled the Google Maps ApI for Android in the Credentials. I have given all the permissions, that are needed for maps, in Manifestfile.xml, my manifest file is as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.samplemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyClOHCG7SBYxg1o6YdUWhn03VSqWwE1y_g"/>
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my activity that extends MapActivity:

```
package com.example.mapsample;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class GoogleMaps_Sample extends MapActivity{

public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.googlemapssample);

}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

When I use the above activity, grids are displayed. When I extends FragmentActivity instead of MapAcitivity and fragment instead of mapview, I have been getting an error saying unfortunately stopped and some times it says some  fragment class error.

I have also installed Google API system image for the emulator I am using. I have downloaded Google Play Services too. But still, maps is not displayed to me. I have done almost everything as suggested in other questions.

What is the error or mistake in my application that is preventing maps to get displayed and that displays grid instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work on a device?

Comment: Have you checked out Vogella's [Android Maps tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#maps_mapsview)? It details v2 Maps as well. Alternatively, you can use the latest version of Google Maps by checking out the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) page of the Maps Android documentation.

Comment: @nasch
ya, I have tried it. Grids are displayed in the emulator and in the mobile too.

Comment: @adjuremods
I have tried it just now. It says unfortunately stopped. I have tried to know the error by using try-catch. But it still did not display the error. LogCat has displayed many errors like: Couldn't find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng'
and Couldn't find 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment'